# Excel 2013 pivot filter not grouping dates

Tags: excel, date, filter, pivot-table

I'm having the following issue using Excel 2013:

My source data is organized as a table. I have a date column titled `E-Mail-Datum`, formatted as date in `dd.mm.yyyy`.

Applying the regular filter directly to the source data table nicely groups the dates together as expected, such that one needs to expand year and month within the filter overlay in order to choose a specific date.

But when I create a pivot table on this source data table, I would expect the same when filtering for the same `dd.mm.yyyy`-formatted date column. This is not the case: The filter overlay shows every single date in a simple (pretty Long) list, not grouping by month/year at all.

How can I get the pivot filter to group dates by year/month?

Comment: When you right click on the dates field in the pivot what options are you presented with?

Comment: @Stefan Klocke: Did my explanation below address your question?

Answer (score 1):

I think I had a similar problem. The date data looked good in the column, but was not being recognized as a date in the Pivot Table, so Date grouping (e.g. Month, Year) was not available. The solution for me was to change the `Number Format` to `Text` (in the main spreadsheet), then change it back to `Date`. After that, Date grouping options were available.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that this is just the way it is...the Tables autofilter automatically groups those dates, but the PivotTable filter doesn't. You can always use the Group Field option from the *PivotTable Tools > Analyze* tab to group by Year and Month, so that you have separate fields for both, if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a workaround, but not a fix,
Create a new column called day and give it the formula

- =DAY([@Date])  (if you have created set the data as a table)
- =Day(A1)       (if it is normal data)

Then use Day instead of Days in the pivot table
If you don't know how to do this here are the instructions
Drag Date down to columns
Go to a date field in the pivot table --> right click --> group

1. Select Years, Month, Days
2. Drag Years and Month to the filter box
3. Drag Days out of the pivot table to the selection box
4. Drag Day into the filter box replacing "Days" with "Day"

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I already did this. Yet, this workaround may not always be such a pleasing solution ... In cases where I e.g. want to Pivot over the last week of January and the first week of February, I'd select the days of the first/last weeks as well as Jan/Feb from a =MONTH(A1) column. This will then give me the first/last weeks for Jan/Feb ... Anyway, I'm just gonna wait for the 2016 rollout :P